# Why bower installs latest versions of packages and not the exact ones that I want?

Tags: bower, bower-install

Having this in bower.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "2.2.4",
        "html5shiv": "3.6.2"
    }
}
```

and running

> bower install

bower installing not this versions but the latest ones (jquery 3.0.0-rc1 & html5shiv 3.7.3 as for now). Why so? I don't have any other dependencies which can require the newest versions.

This is bower install log

> bower cached        https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.4
> bower validate      2.2.4 against https://github.com/jquery/jquery-dist.git#2.2.4
> bower cached        https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv.git#3.6.2
> bower validate      3.6.2 against https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv.git#3.6.2
> bower install       jquery#2.2.4
> bower install       html5shiv#3.6.2
> jquery#2.2.4 bower_components\jquery
> html5shiv#3.6.2 bower_components\html5shiv

And it's strange for me that .bower.json for html5shiv looks like this

```
{
  "name": "html5shiv",
  "version": "3.6.2",
  "main": [
    "dist/html5shiv.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "composer.json",
    "test",
    "build",
    "src",
    "build.xml"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv",
  "_release": "3.6.2",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "version",
    "tag": "3.6.2",
    "commit": "f65f9b0d776ae3b88d4c7f0b27c64e384aee47aa"
  },
  "_source": "https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv.git",
  "_target": "3.6.2",
  "_originalSource": "html5shiv"
}
```

but bower.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "html5shiv",
  "version": "3.7.3",
  "main": [
    "dist/html5shiv.js"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "composer.json",
    "test",
    "build",
    "src",
    "build.xml"
  ]
}
```

The same is for jQuery. .bower.json referencing the version that I want, but bower.json referencing the latest version. And like I said, source and dist files are from the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the # before the version
for example

```
{ 
    "name": "test",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "#2.2.4"    
    }
}
```

You can find [more about bower here](http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-package-manager-bower-and-using-gulp-to-manage-components)

Comment: Actually it was a cache problem. I needed to clean bower cache. And then I was able to install versions I needed even without #. Sorry for a noob question. But it's still a mystery for me, why bower installs cached version even when I change version number in bower.json?